# Testing for causality with Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, svm, causality

Can a support vector machine (SVM) be used to test for causality between 2 or more variables?

I know that the original purpose for SVM is classification. I also know that there is a variation of the SVM which is used for regression. The latter is called Support Vector Regression (SVR).

However, is there any paper/ study that used a Support Vector Machine/ Regression to test the causality between 2 or more variables?

Comment: Do you have anything concrete in mind, or is the question as general as it appears?

Comment: Causality testing goes way beyond any machine learning method I know of. Mutual and hidden-variable causation are hard to disambiguate, you need domain knowledge to help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVM can be used to generate predicted values, which can be used as estimates of propensity scores or potential outcomes, just like any other supervised machine learning method. It is not special in that regard. These predicted values can be used to estimate causal effects when other assumptions about the data-generating process are known.

In addition, [Ratkovic (2014)](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Eratkovic/public/BinMatchSVM.pdf) proposed a form of matching with SVM that can be used to estimate causal effects. The method is available in the R package `SVMMatch`. The method has received little attention.